# Magento, indexing issue(one or more indexs are invalid)

Tags: magento, magento2

As a magento newby I have installed magento 2.1.8. After the install I get an error in the admin saying that one or more indexers are invalid, so I have found some help online showing how to reindex, but when I use these commandlines I get errors back saying...

```
php bin/magento index:reindex 

[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory   

[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Install is on localhost -> MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you remove store or website not properly. Check the **store_group** and **store_website**  table and compare the entry with **Content -> Configurations** in Magento admin. Remove additional entry from database. I had personally used it and its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]" error is usually related to the MySQL DB being down and/or Magento being unable to connect to it.

**Before**

[image: MySql Server Stopped]

[image: SQLSTATE <HY000> [2002]]

**After**

[image: MySql server Restarted]

[image: Site Is Operational]

Please check if:
(a) Your MySQL instance is up and running.
(b) The user account, your Magento instance is setup to use, can connect to the MySQL DB and also has sufficient grants/privileges to access the Magento DB tables.

*P.S:* When you say you've installed Magento, I'm assuming you cloned the github repo and ran through the appropriate Magento setup/install steps ... Correct?